# Auto shrink/expand a <select> based on selected option using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

Lets say you have an select with:

```
<select>
  <option>Short</option>
  <option>A little bit longer</option>
  <option>Really super duper long and amazing</option>
</select>
```

I've added styling to make it look like plain text, but I need to display an arrow next to the element - the problem is that i cant figure out how to make the size of the select based on the size of the selected option.

See this picture, and it'll make sense:

I want the arrow to be right next to the selected option:
[image: I want the arrow to be right next to the selected option]

Put on shorter elements, the select is still the width of the longest option:
[image: Put on shorter elements, the select is still the width of the longest option]

**Is there any way to solve this in a pure-css way?**

Comment: You have to transform the `<select>` to something like Select2 or replace it as HTML and not the component.

Comment: css is for styling not really for programming logic (i.e. _When dynamic text is X length do this, else do that_). For that you will need javascript.

Comment: @zgood well, yes, that is actually what CSS can be used for - you can expand elements to fit text. You dont even need fancy flexbox to do that, thats just plain old CSS1 :)